# iTunes Lookup API, get iPhone 5 app screenshots

Tags: iphone, app-store, screenshot, itunes

I use **iTunes API lookup** to get app data by App ID this way:
http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=543891460&lang=ru

Even if app is designed for **iPhone5**, in JSON I get **3.5 inch** screenshots (under **screenshotUrls** array).
Is there any way to get **4 inch**. screenshots?

Comment: is your simulator is in 4 inch mode? if not,set your simulator to 4 inch mode

Comment: I use browser and enter this url: http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=543891460&lang=ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check again.

Apple seems to be rolling out new 4 inch screenshots since a few hours.

Screenshots now also have the pixel-size in the filename. Well, kind of: it doesn’t seem to be 100% correct (yet?).  The possible values are:

- xxx.xxxxxxxx.**1136x1136-75**.jpg (4" iPhone)
- xxx.xxxxxxxx.**320x480-75**.jpg (3.5" iPhone)
- xxx.xxxxxxxx.**480x480-75**.jpg (iPad)

Comment: This does not work with the current version of iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to access all screenshots using the inofficial iTunes Connect API:

`https://itunesconnect.apple.com//WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/apps/version/[app_id]`

It contains all existing screenshots in all resolution in the original format.

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to map the language with the one used by the iTunes Transporter.

There is a pull request, adding this feature to `deliver`: https://github.com/KrauseFx/deliver/pull/113/files

Update: a mapping of language codes to languages can be found here: https://github.com/KrauseFx/deliver/blob/master/lib/assets/DeliverLanguageMapping.json