# iTunes Lookup all screenshot versions?

Tags: ios, macos, itunes

Is there a way to systematically retrieve all screenshots (3.5 inch iphone, 4 inch iphone, and ipad) for an app (or hundreds)?

The iTunes search API does not seem to return 3.5 inch screenshots if 4 inch screenshots are available.

I saw an approach outlined in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164847/itunes-lookup-api-get-iphone-5-app-screenshots), but it was not reliable (couldn't get it to work for 5 separate apps).

I'm open to using iTMSTransporter CLI, although I couldn't find anything in the ~190 pages of AppMetadataSpecification5.1Revision1.pdf and Transporter_User_Guide_1.7.9.pdf that helped. If you want these pdfs (and have xcode installed), run:

`./iTMSTransporter -m downloadMetadataGuides -u [itunes username] -p [itunes pw] -vendor_id [vendor_id] -destination .`

from:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/bin`

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to access all screenshots using the inofficial iTunes Connect API:

`https://itunesconnect.apple.com//WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/apps/version/[app_id]`

It contains all existing screenshots in all resolution in the original format.

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to map the language with the one used by the iTunes Transporter.

There is a pull request, adding this feature to `deliver`: https://github.com/fastlane-old/deliver/pull/113/files

Update: a mapping of language codes to languages can be found here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fastlane-old/deliver/d9a43d3342e6b1d8ddac802e6557e482932a9ac2/lib/assets/DeliverLanguageMapping.json